# what should be added in <form method="post" action="" > ,when i enter any page in action only that page opens

Tags: php, html, web

i m working on a website the html code is working but php code is not working.what should be added in  ,when i enter any page in action only that page open.it not proceed the other pages below in switch statement

```
<p class="h2">Quick Search</p>
    <div class="sb2_opts">
     <p>
   </p>
<form method="post" action="" >
 <p>Enter your source and destination.</p>
<p>
    From:</p>
<select name="from">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<p>
    To:</p>
   <select name="To">
<option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
<option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
<option value="murree">Murree</option>
<option value="Muzaffarabad">Muzaffarabad</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="search" /> 
</form>
</form> </table>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['from']) and isset($_POST['To'])) {
$from = $_POST['from'] ;
$to = $_POST['To'] ;
$table = array($from, $to);

switch ($table) {
  case array ("Islamabad", "Lahore") :
  header("Location: page1.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Murree") :
  header("Location: page2.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Muzaffarabad") :
 header("Location: page3.html");
 break;
//.....
//......
default:
echo "Your choice is nor valid !!";
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

php is case sensitive language, your switch case statement will work when your post string is equal to your conditions. so try this .

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['from']) && isset($_POST['To'] ) ) {
$from = strtolower($_POST['from']);
$to = strtolower($_POST['To']);
$table = array($from, $to);

switch ($table) {
  case array ("Islamabad", "Lahore") :
  header("Location: page1.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Murree") :
  header("Location: page2.html");
 break;
  case array ("Islamabad", "Muzaffarabad") :
 header("Location: page3.html");
 break;
//.....
//......
default:
echo "Your choice is nor valid !!";
}

}
?>
```